# Is each preseparable topological group narrow?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

A topological group $G$ is defined to be

$\bullet$ *precompact* if for any neighborhood $U\subseteq G$ of the unit there exists a finite subset $F\subseteq G$ such that $G=UF$;

$\bullet$ *narrow* if for any neighborhood $U\subseteq G$ of the unit there exists a countable subset $S\subseteq G$ such that $G=US$;

$\bullet$ *separable* if there exists a countable subset $S\subseteq G$ such that for any neighborhood $U\subseteq G$ of the unit we have $G=SU$;

$\bullet$ *preseparable* if there exists a countable subset $S\subseteq G$ such that for any neighborhood $U\subseteq G$ of the unit there exists a finite subset $F\subseteq G$ such that $G=SUF$.

Let us observe the following facts concerning those concepts:

1. A topological group is preseparable if it is precompact or separable.
2. More generally, a topological group $G$ is preseparable if $G$ contains a separable closed normal subgroup $H$ whose quotient group $G/H$ is precompact. In the latter case the group $G$ is also narrow.
3. Each preseparable abelian topological group is narrow.
4. For any cardinal $\kappa>\mathfrak c$, the Tychonoff power $\mathbb R^\kappa$ is an example 
   of a narrow abelian topological group which is not preseparable.

> **Problem.** Is each preseparable topological group narrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan Pachl has informed me that the answer to this problem is affirmative and can be derived from the following helpful fact, proved in Lemma 3.31 of his book ["Uniform spaces and measures"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461450573). I also remember that a similar theorem was proved in the book "Topologies on groups determined by sequences" by I.Protasov and E.Zelenyuk.

> **Theorem.** If a group $G$ is written as $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_iA$ for some sets $U_1,\dots,U_n,A\subset G$, then $G=U_i^{-1}U_iB$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and some set $B\subseteq G$ of cardinality $|B|\le f(n,|A|)$, where the function $f(n,\kappa)$ is defined by the recursive formula: $f(1,\kappa)=\kappa$ and $f(n,\kappa)=f(n-1,\kappa+\kappa^2)$. In particular, $f(n,\kappa)=\kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ and any $n\in\mathbb N$.

*Proof.* The proof is by induction on $n$. For $n=1$ it is trivial. Assume that the theorem is proved for all $k<n$. Write $G$ as $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_iA$ for some sets $U_1,\dots,U_n,A\subset G$. If $U_n^{-1}U_nA=G$, then we are done. If $U_n^{-1}U_nA\ne G$, then we can choose a point $x\in G\setminus U_n^{-1}U_nA$ and conclude that $U_nx\cap U_nA=\emptyset$ and hence $U_nx\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}U_iA$. Then $U_nA\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}U_iAx^{-1}A$ and $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i(A\cup Ax^{-1}A)$. By the induction hypothesis, there exists $i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ and a set $B\subset G$ of cardinality $|B|\le f(n-1,|A\cup Ax^{-1}A|)\le f(n-1,|A|+|A|^2)=f(n,|A|)$ such that $G=U_i^{-1}U_iB$.